# NodeJS - Image displayed from MongoDB as an empty square

Tags: node.js, mongodb, image, buffer

I want to store an image in MongoDB using NodeJS. I have managed to insert an image in database, as an object with `Buffer` and `img` parameters. However, when I display it, I get an empty square instead. Anyone knows how to fix this?

Code :

```
var imgPath = '.public/images/image.png';

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
const assert = require('assert');
const dbName = 'database';
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
     console.log("Connected successfully to server");

     const db = client.db(dbName);
     var collectionClient = db.collection('collection1');

     var store = {
          img: {
              data: Buffer,
              contentType: String
          }
     };

    store.img.data = fs.readFileSync(imgPath);
    store.img.contentType = 'image/png';

    collectionClient.insertMany([store], function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Insert failed', err);
        } else {
            console.log('Insert successful');
        }    
    });

});


MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("database");
    dbo.collection("collection1").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;

        router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
            res.contentType(result[0].img.contentType);
            res.send(result[0].img.data);

        });
         db.close();

     });
});
```

Comment: Can you please share your mongo img document? My first hunch is that it has something to do with the encoding, e.g res.end(result[0].img.data, 'binary'); but to check it it would be better to have the mongo document

Answer (score 0):

Instead, try this:

```
const download = Buffer.from((result[0].img.data).toString('utf-8','base64'));  
res.end(download);
```